# Python work out difference to 0

Tags: python

A user can only gain 100 points in a day. If the user gains more than 100 points I only want the value of `delta` to be the difference for example...

> If a user has 100 (current_rep) and adds 10, then I want delta = 0
>
> If a user has 90 (current_rep) and adds 20, then I want delta = 10

This is what I have so far:

```
REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY = 100
current_rep = self.model.objects.calculate_points_for_today(user)
expected_rep = reputation_value + current_rep

if expected_rep > REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY:
   delta = REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY - current_rep
```

But above gives delta as a - not the allowed points.

Comment: Slightly off topic but your variable names are ambiguous/confusing. I'd expect `current_rep` to be the reputation at the user (not points for today as implied by the method). I'm not sure what `expected_rep` would be. The reputation of the user after adding today's gain? Before or after limiting it to the daily cap? What about something like `reputation_gained_today`, `reputation_before_today` and `total_reputation_after_today`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the condition you can make it work, but to make it more readable use the built-in [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)

```
REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY = 100
current_rep = self.model.objects.calculate_points_for_today(user)
expected_rep = min(reputation_value + current_rep, REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY )
delta = expected_rep - current_rep
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the conditional statement that will work for you

```
if expected_rep > REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY:
   expected_rep = REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY
delta = expected_rep - current_rep
```

Comment: *If a user has 90 (current_rep) and adds 20, then I want delta = 10*...I do not believe your conditional satisfies this condition.

Comment: Not sure if thats works how I need it to. If a user already gain 90 which is current_rep for that day and the expected_rep is 20 then delta should be 10.

Answer (score 0):

your if condition is backwards.

i think you mean to do:

```
if expected_rep <= REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY:
   delta = REPUTATION_MAX_GAIN_PER_DAY - current_rep
```

Comment: the condition works, its the value of delta thats wrong. if I try to add 90 to a user who already has 10 then the value of delta should be 10. If a try to add 1 to a user who already has 100 then delta should = 0.

Comment: @OrbiterFleet Why do you want the delta to be 10 in that case? Your original question states the opposite. In fact, the code you already have perfectly fulfills the requirements in your question.

Comment: Updated OP to make more sense.

Comment: @OrbiterFleet, you stated you only want delta to be positive value if the difference is below 100, otherwise delta should be zero. this would meet your goal...